# How do i get accurate Wifi getLinkSpeed MBPS

Tags: android, android-networking

I'm trying to get my current Wifi internet speed in MBPS my android app, and compare it's results to https://fast.com result.

So i'm using android WifiInfo: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiInfo.html#getLinkSpeed

```
WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(context.WIFI_SERVICE);
WifiInfo info = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
float linkSpeed = info.getLinkSpeed(); // linkSpeed gives me 65
```

Which is suppose to mean 65Mbps according to the docs. But when i checked fast.com result, i got 2.9 Mbps.

Which seems like my getLinkSpeed() result wasn't true or maybe i'm misinterpreting it. Please anyone has an idea of how to get accurate Wifi speed. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your Wi-Fi speed does not equal to your external internet speed.
`getLinkSpeed()` returns a local wifi network speed. But external internet access speed may (and will) differ.

`getLinkSpeed()` will return near-accurate WIFI-network speed. But to measure your internet connection speed, you'll have to for example download some file from the internet, and do the following:

```
speed = file_size / time_to_download
```

Comment: Ok, but then it also depends on how big the file is, doesn't it?

Comment: @HtmlTosin, it shouldn't depend on the file size. 
You also can try using some already-made speed test libs like this https://github.com/bertrandmartel/speed-test-lib

Comment: Thanks, checking this out